# How to format objective-c tow parameter block with clang-format?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang-format

I have the following code, for example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}]
```

When I apply clang-format on it, it turns into:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:^{

}
    completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
```

As you can see, The second block parameter in a new line.

My style :

```
AlignTrailingComments: true
BasedOnStyle: Chromium
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
ColumnLimit: 0
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 8
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
PointerBindsToType: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
#SpaceInEmptyParentheses: true
SpacesInParentheses: false
UseTab: Never
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
#SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
```